# Remove only one element from duplicated list

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a simple list with same elements:

```
private List<String> boxes = new ArrayList<>();
    boxes.add("100");
    boxes.add("20");
    boxes.add("20");
    boxes.add("5");
    boxes.add("5");
    boxes.add("5");
    boxes.add("5");
    boxes.add("5");
    boxes.add("Extra life");
    boxes.add("Game over");
    boxes.add("Game over");
    boxes.add("Game over");
```

I would like to remove a "Game over" value from this list, but only one, not all three. How can I do it? I tried to call `remove` method on this list but it removes all threee elements.

Comment: `remove` removes the **first occurance** of the parameter passed in the list.

Comment: **Unable to reproduce** *"I tried to call remove method on this list but it removes all threee elements"*. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/491gsj) for proof that `remove` works. As nits.kk mentioned, javadoc of [`remove(str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) says: *Removes the **first occurrence** of the specified element from this list, if it is present.*

Answer (score 2):

You can use this overload of the [`remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) method:

```
boxes.remove("Game over");
```

Comment: this is a better approach. It is simpler and different implementation will use appropriate strategy. Specifically ArrayList and LinkedList will use index and iterator respectively. All from JDK, well tested.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void remove(List<String> boxes, String str) {
    int index = boxes.indexOf(str);

    if(index >= 0)
        boxes.remove(index);
}
```

One thing about it. I am worrying about concrete implementation of `List<String>`. In some cases, `boxes.remove(index)` could take `O(n)`. So think implementation with `Iterator` could be better (but not critical). It loop given list only once.

```
public static void remove(List<String> boxes, String str) {
    Iterator<String> it = boxes.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (it.next().equals(str)) {
            it.remove();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover, as mentioned by *@Andreas*, `List.remove(Object)` removes only first found element. Approach that you tried seems to be working correctly:

```
public static void remove(List<String> boxes, String str) {
    boxes.remove(str);
}
```

Comment: Why not just [`remove(str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-): *Removes the **first occurrence** of the specified element from this list, if it is present.*

Comment: @Andreas yes, I have checked. It really works as well.